# Copy Stack or Queue without using "clone"

Tags: java, stack, queue

Copy stack and queue without using clone. For example, when I call a method passing a stack, I cannot modify leave the original Stacks passed. I need to make a copy / clone of the passed Stack to alter / use in the method.

I can only use Stack.java (attached). I have created the following helper methods:

```
public static Stack<CalendarDate> qToS(Queue<CalendarDate> q) {
    Stack<CalendarDate> s = new Stack<CalendarDate>();
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
       CalendarDate n = q.remove();
       s.push(n);
    }
    return s; // Return stack s
}

public static Queue<CalendarDate> sToQ(Stack<CalendarDate> s) {
    Queue<CalendarDate> q = new LinkedList<CalendarDate>();
    while (!s.empty()) {
       CalendarDate n = s.pop();
       q.add(n);
    }
    return q; // Return queue q
}

/*      
    Provided as a Stack Class alternative
    Limits user to actual Stack methods
    so Vector<E> is not available
*/
public class Stack<E> {
    // avoid blanked import of java.util
    private java.util.Stack<E> secret;

    // default constructor
    public Stack() {
        secret = new java.util.Stack<E>();
    } 

    // empty that collection
    public void clear() {
        secret.clear();
    }

    // should be order constant
    public int size() {
        return secret.size();
    }

    // simply have push call push from API
    public E push(E a) {
        secret.push(a);
        return a;
    }

    // And, empty calls empty from API
    public boolean empty() {
        return secret.empty();
    }

    // And my pop() uses pop() form JAVA API
    public E pop() {
        return secret.pop();
    }

    // My peek uses their peek
    public E peek() {
        return secret.peek();
    }

    // Following are not basic Stack operations
    // but needed to do some simple testing

    // toString is probably not O(constant)
    public String toString() {
        return secret.toString();
    }

}
```

MY SOLUTION

```
public static Stack<CalendarDate> sToS(Stack<CalendarDate> orgin) {
        // Create a temp stack
        Stack<CalendarDate> temp = new Stack<CalendarDate>();

        // Move all values from origin
        // stack to temp stack using pop and push
        while (!orgin.empty()) {
            CalendarDate n = orgin.pop();
            temp.push(n);    // push here for the same order
        }

        // Create a copy stack
        Stack<CalendarDate> copy = new Stack<CalendarDate>();

        // Move all values from temp stack to
        // both origin and copy stacks at the same time
        while (!temp.empty()) {
            CalendarDate n = temp.pop();
            copy.push(n);    // push here for the same order
            orgin.push(n);  
        }

        return copy;
    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?  What issues are you having with your code?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, exactly. It seems here like this is a homework. This is fine, we might help you with that, in some ways, but we won't simply do it for you. You have the beginning of a working solution. Now what? You are blocked? You don't know how to do something? Something is not working as you expected? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a stack:

- Create a `temp` stack
- Move all values from `origin` stack to `temp` stack using `pop` and `push`
- `origin` stack is now empty, and `temp` stack is inverted
- Create a `copy` stack
- Move all values from `temp` stack to both `origin` and `copy` stacks at the same time
- `origin` is back to original content, and `copy` stack has same content.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a scenario where you've three Stacks, Stack A (the one you want to copy from), Stack B (the destination to which you want to copy), and a Stack temp (helper Stack).

```
Step 1: (The Initial Stack)

|1|  | |  | |
|2|  | |  | |
|3|  | |  | |

 A   TEMP  B

Step 2: (Move elements from Stack A to Temp Stack)

| |  | |  | |
|2|  | |  | |
|3|  |1|  | |

 A   TEMP  B

| |  | |  | |
| |  |2|  | |
|3|  |1|  | |

 A   TEMP  B

| |  |3|  | |
| |  |2|  | |
| |  |1|  | |

 A   TEMP  B

Step 3: (Move elements from Temp stack to Stack A & B)

| |  | |  | |
| |  |2|  | |
|3|  |1|  |3|

 A   TEMP  B

| |  | |  | |
|2|  | |  |2|
|3|  |1|  |3|

 A   TEMP  B

|1|  | |  |1|
|2|  | |  |2|
|3|  | |  |3|

 A   TEMP  B
```

The best way to fully understand is to take an example and try it out yourself. Or you can simply search for an approach on coding platforms like [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/)

Comment: That leaves `A` empty, but question says *"I cannot modify leave the original Stacks passed"*, which I interpret as "I cannot modify the original stack, i.e. the passed stack must be left unchanged".

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I forgot to insert elements to A while inserting into B.